# Query of two tables possibly a union

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Classes (
    Class_ID Varchar2(2) CONSTRAINT Classes_Class_ID_Pk PRIMARY KEY,
    Class_Name VARCHAR(15) CONSTRAINT Classes_Class_Name_NN NOT NULL,
    Price Number(5, 2),
    Start_Date DATE,
    End_Date DATE,
    Start_Time Varchar2(5),
    End_Time Varchar2(5),
    Day VARCHAR(10),
    Trainer_ID CONSTRAINT Classes_Trainer_ID_FK REFERENCES Trainers(Trainer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ClassSchedule (
    Class_ID Varchar2(2) CONSTRAINT Classes_Class_ID_FK REFERENCES Classes(Class_ID),
    Member_ID Varchar2(2) CONSTRAINT Members_Member_ID_FK REFERENCES Members(Member_ID),
    Paid CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT ClassSchedule_Combo_PK PRIMARY KEY (Class_ID, Member_ID)
);
```

Now for each class I want to list the class id, class name the price per class, the count of members in each class, and the total revenue for each class. I only want to show those groups that are over $400 and sort them by the calculated total. Here is my query that isn't working:

```
SELECT
    C.Class_Id,
    Class_Name,
    Price,
    Count(S.Member_Id) AS Student_Count,
    (Student_Count * Price) AS Class_Revenue
FROM Classes C,
     ClassSchedule S
WHERE C.Class_ID = S.Class_Id
  AND (Student_Count * Price) > 400
ORDER BY Class_Revenue DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated. Been banging my head up against the wall trying to get it to work.

Comment: without "group by" clause how can you use aggregate function...

Answer (score 0):

```
select Class_Id,Class_Name,Price,Student_Count*Price Class_Revenue from 
(Select 
C.Class_Id, 
Class_Name, 
Price, 
Count(S.Member_Id) As Student_Count
From Classes C, ClassSchedule S
Where C.Class_ID = S.Class_Id
group by C.Class_Id, 
Class_Name, 
Price
)
where having (Student_Count*Price) > 400
Order By Class_Revenue Desc;
```

Comment: Sorry that I missed the group by. I actually did have it. That is where I am having the problem. I keep getting an error that says "Not a group by expression".

Comment: Yes. When I try a group by using class_id or the class_name, I get that error "not a group by expression".

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `over` clause on the `count()`:

```
select Class_Id, 
       Class_Name,
       Price,
       Student_Count,
       (Student_Count * Price) AS Class_Revenue
from
(SELECT
    C.Class_Id,
    Class_Name,
    Price,
    Count(S.Member_Id) over (partition by C.Class_Id) AS Student_Count
FROM Classes C,
     ClassSchedule S
WHERE C.Class_ID = S.Class_Id) t
where (Student_Count * Price) > 400
order by (Student_Count * Price) desc
```

Comment: This worked but now I need to only show each entry once. Any ideas?

Comment: @Will1973 - Then you do need a group by... see [Avi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16272424/1083652)